# How to isolate an internal server error on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, running on Cloud9. In this environment, if anything goes wrong - typically a typo on my part - I get the "internal server error" from the server, and "something went wrong" in the browser. No other information is provided. It appears that the only way to troubleshoot is to comment out lines until the error disappears. (I've spent hundreds of hours in debuggers on other platforms/languages, and find this extremely inefficient.)

Cloud9 says they don't support Ruby in their debugger. I'm guessing that fact  means they can't identify the line in the source that generated the error.

Is there any way to investigate server errors on Cloud9 other than just commenting out code?

Comment: Commenting out half the document at a time to narrow down the bug / typo is actually a valid and helpful debugging method - especially for finding missing `end` statements.

Comment: That is what I'm resorting to, but it would be far more efficient if I could get  a log of some kind, identifying at least which source file I was processing - obviously, a source line number would be far better. Is there no way to get anything more than a generic "internal server error" on cloud9?